# In 'Paper Moon', is Addie the daughter of Moses?

Tags: character, paper-moon

Throughout the movie *Paper Moon*, it's hinted that Addie is the daughter of Moses. But it is never confirmed or denied.

Since this is based on a novel, I was wondering if there is any canonical information on whether they were father and daughter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [IMDB's FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070510/faq) regarding the film;

> The question is left unanswered in both the movie and the novel. **Moses
> denies it, and Addie states that her mother was the wildest girl in
> her town and that Moses is one of *three* possible fathers for her.**
>
> However, most viewers of the movie tend to believe that Moses is
> indeed Addie's father. In real life, Ryan O'Neal IS Tatum O'Neal's
> father. Her mother is actress Joanna Cook Moore.

You're left to make up your own mind. Personally I believe that the resemblance (in the film) strongly indicates that she is indeed his biological daughter.